# How do i get SerialNumber of BaseBoard with WMI?

Tags: wmi, powerbuilder, wql

A nice example is there to use **WMI** in Powerbuilder that terminates a running process.

The same technique can be used to get **SerialNumber** of **BaseBoard**. I need to extend the same code to handle return values of the WQL query.

**The WQL query i want to execute is:**

```
SELECT Product, SerialNumber FROM Win32_BaseBoard
```

I can execute the query above but dont know how to save the **SerialNumber** in a variable after the **ExecuteStatement**() function is called.

Please take a look at the link for complete PowerBuilder code. 
[How to terminate a process if it has specific folder name in its path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880237/how-to-terminate-a-process-if-it-has-specific-folder-name-in-its-path/49990491#49990491)

Following is a portion of a sample code taken from the link above to show the function.

```
wsh = CREATE OleObject
wsh.ConnectToNewObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
wsh.Language = "VBScript"
wsh.AddCode(TheCode)
TRY
    wsh.ExecuteStatement(FunctionName)
CATCH (RunTimeError Re01)
    MessageBox("Query Error", "Following code has some problems.~r~n~r~n" +                 TheCode, StopSign!)
END TRY
wsh.DisconnectObject()

DESTROY wsh
```

The important function call
    **wsh.ExecuteStatement(FunctionName)**

**What to do after that function call to set my PowerBuilder local variables with the returned** SerialNumber **of** BaseBoard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OLEObject ole_wsh
Any la_baseboard[]
string ls_message

 ole_wsh = CREATE OLEObject
 ole_wsh.ConnectToNewObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
 ole_wsh.Language = "vbscript"
 ole_wsh.AddCode('Function rtnBaseBoard()~r~n' &
 + 'DIM objBaseBoard(2)~r~n'  &
 + 'strComputer = "."~r~n'  &
 + 'Set objWMIService ='  &
 + '   GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")~r~n' &
 + 'Set colItems =' &
 + '    objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT Product, SerialNumber FROM Win32_BaseBoard")~r~n' &
 + 'For Each objItem in colItems~r~n' &
 + 'objBaseBoard(0) = objItem.Product~r~n' &
 + 'objBaseBoard(1) = objItem.SerialNumber~r~n' &
 + 'Next~r~n' &
 + 'rtnBaseBoard = objBaseBoard~r~n' &
 + 'End Function')
 la_baseboard[] = ole_wsh.Eval("rtnBaseBoard")
 ole_wsh.DisconnectObject()
 DESTROY ole_wsh

ls_message = "Product: " + string(la_baseboard[1]) + "~r~n" + &
+ "SerialNumber: " + string(la_baseboard[2]) + "~r~n" 
MessageBox("Win32 BaseBoard",ls_message)
```

Comment: I am trying to do this + 'objProcessor(thecounter) = CStr(objItem(thecounter))~r~n'  and then keep increment the loop counter but after everything when this line execute la_processor = ole_wsh.Eval("rtnProcessor") i get runtime error. How to avoid specific property name in statement like 'objBaseBoard(0) = objItem.Product~r~n' and get all properties in Any array of PowerBuilder? Not really needed to have everything displayed but just to know if it is possible. Thanks

Comment: I cannot fathom how running the Windows Script Host as an OLE object to execute a VBscript to execute a WMI query is the best answer for this problem.  WMI has its own COM object interface, would that not be more straightforward?  Is there something about PB's OLE object interface that makes that impossible?